# warning: pipe flag `D' requires dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I have a problem in my postfix. I'm setting my server mail by postfix + dovecot + spamassassin and clamav.
When I send a multiple email I have the below warning in the log.

```
Dec 14 12:37:52 mydomain postfix/pipe[30312]: 72210100722: to=<john.doe@mydomain.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.35, delays=0.23/0/0/0.11, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (mail system configuration error)
Dec 14 12:37:52 mydomain postfix/pipe[30312]: warning: pipe flag `D' requires dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

apparently this solved adding

```
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

into /etc/postfix/main.cf

and

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Now It works!

Comment: You saved my life; I would never find this solution without a hint.